# Finding the roots of this multivariable polynomial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots

My polynomial is this ten term monster
$P(x,y,z) = 6561 x^3+486 x^2+12 x+6561 y^3+1944 y^2+192 y+6561 z^3+6318 z^2+2028 z+223$

It's simplest form is ${1 \over 81} \left( (81x+2)^3 + (81y+8)^3 +(81z+26)^3 -33 \right)$

I'm tackling the problem of representing the number $33$ as the sum of three integer cubes, and if this polynomial has an integer root, then that will immediately supply the representation of $33$

Comment: quick analysis by mod 8 shows two even and one odd number in solution and the two even numbers need to have same parity of number 0f 2s in factor

Comment: by analysis mod 9 x^3,y^3,z^3 = -1 mod 9 because 6 = -3 mod 9 and x^3=1,0,-1 mod 9